# Why is wp-includes/js/shortcode.js rendered in gibberish

Tags: javascript, wordpress, syntax-error

I noticed my debugger was flaring up for a javascript error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
http://vionms.beee/wp/wp-includes/js/shortcode.js?ver=4.9.8 line 1
```

When I open it, it shows a lot of gibberish... and then some (partial) information about a Comodo RSA domain validation/SSL wildcard, see screenshot.

[image: screenshot of error]

I deactivated all plugins and reverted to a WP default theme, but the error persisted...

If I remove the version from the url, the scripts shows its contents (as expected).

I've never seen this before... and I don't know what caused it, so annoying...

Comment: maybe your Wordpress site get hacked? You can compare your file with a fresh one: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/shortcode.js

Comment: No it is not, it's a local installation...

Comment: Maybe reinstall WordPress.. Or try private browsing to bypass cache..

Comment: It appears the problem is gone. Don't know what solved it, but most likely the update to 5.0. Don't ask me why :)